# Swift and inheritenance

Tags: ios, swift

Likely a silly question and I am over looking something absurd

I have two physical swift files in the same project
The first file is called DataManagerBase.swift

```
import Foundation

class DataManagerBase
{
    let baseUrl:NSString = "holder"

    init()
    {
        //Do Work
    }

    func DoWok()
    {

    }
}
```

The second file is UserManager.swift

```
import Foundation

class UserManager:DataManagerBase
{
    func DoesUserHaveAccess(userReq : UserRequest) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

}
```

However xcode throws an error saying
Use of undeclared type 'DataManager'

Answer (score 2):

Your class is `DataManagerBase` not `DataManager`

Comment: typo in the question on my part .. wasnt  the problem .. i am dling the newest beta though, may that be the issue?

Comment: still an issue ever after grabing beta3

Answer (score 0):

Fix it .. stupid base class was added to my "test" target membership, not the membership of the api